# extracting country, state, city or state name from SOLR query after spell check

Tags: java, solr

I've got a directory listing of businesses.

If the user searches **"plumbing businesses in new york"** the query should return all the plumbing businesses in our Solr index **AND** should also run a sub-query which will return all the plumbing businesses in new york.

In solr I will use the stopwords.txt file to remove the "in" from the query.

It is possible that user can make a spelling mistake of spelling "new york" as "new yrok".
For the spelling mistake I can use spellings.txt

In the final query I want to get the name of state, country, street or country and run two queries.

1- "plumbing businesses" which will return all the plumbing businesses in our SOLR index.
2- "plumbing businesses new york" which will return all the plumbing businesses in new york after removing "in" and doing a spell check.

Can anyone please tell me how this is achievable in SOLR ?

Comment: Did you check Solr update processor chains?

Comment: just read about it. Aren't they for updating ? I'm not trying to do any updates. Just select.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a bit of NLP and transform the user's query into a SOLR query.

For example if you have the word `in` you can probably assume that everything before it is a thing that someone is looking for, and everything after it is the place they need to find it. Assuming your schema has fields for business and location its simple to construct a SOLR query using the provided values in the right fields.

Comment: But the user can enter "plumbing businesses new york" without the in. Just like in google and the user can also make a spelling mistake "plumbing businesses new yrok". So that's why I was thinking that if SOLR has a way of recognising countries, states or cities providing it with a country.txt file or something after checking for spelling (spelling.txt) and removing the in keyword (stopwords.txt) ?